# change the column value as per other column and Serialize value after it in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Table Like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33T2q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnSUC.png)

I want to change `ItemOrder` as per `PraticeItem` : if `PraticeItem` is Yes then it should be display 'P1' and 'P2' respectively , I have done this using case Query , but challenge is that i have to serialize `ItemOrder` after that it means after p1,p2 i want it to start with order 1,2,3 and this table contains multiple `ID` , for diffrent `ID` count of `PraticeItem`  is different and for serializing I have to minus that count , so my question is how to find the `PraticeItem` as per `Id` and minus it from `ItemOrder`

my Query is as Below:(I have done this to replace the value of `ItemOrder`)

```
 case when PracticeItem = 'YES' and si.ItemOrder = 1 then  REPLACE(si.ItemOrder,1,'P1')  when PracticeItem = 'YES' and si.ItemOrder = 2  then  REPLACE(si.ItemOrder,2,'P2')  when PracticeItem = 'NO' then REPLACE(si.ItemOrder,si.ItemOrder,si.ItemOrder-(**here i want total PraticeItem count Id wise**)) end as ItemOrder
```

My whole Query is Like this :

```
select  af.OldFormCode,case when PracticeItem = 'YES' and si.ItemOrder = 1 then  REPLACE(si.ItemOrder,1,'P1')  when PracticeItem = 'YES' and si.ItemOrder = 2  then  REPLACE(si.ItemOrder,2,'P2')  when PracticeItem = 'NO' then REPLACE(si.ItemOrder,si.ItemOrder,si.ItemOrder-(select COUNT(PracticeItem) where PracticeItem = 'YES' )) end as ItemOrder ,ISNULL(bi.BankItemCode,'')as BankItemCode,iv.Code,
                        ISNULL((select AltTag from display where Id in (select DisplayVersionId from ItemDisplay where itemId = iv.ID)),'') as AltTag,iv.PracticeItem,af.Code as AssessmentFormCode,af.ModalityId,af.ID 
                            from 
                            SectionItem si Left join AssessmentFormSection afs on si.SectionId= afs.Id 
                            Left join AssessmentForm af on afs.AssessmentFormId = af.ID
                            Left join ItemView iv on iv.ID = si.ItemId
                            Left join BankItemView bi on bi.ItemId = si.ItemId
                            Left Join Draft d on (d.ItemId = si.ItemId and d.Id = CAST((SUBSTRING(si.FinalDraftVersion,3,(CHARINDEX('.',si.FinalDraftVersion,0)-3))) as int))
                            Left Join ItemStatistics ist on ist.ItemId = iv.ID and ist.AssessmentId = af.ID
                            where af.ID in (3287,3251)  order by af.ID,si.ItemOrder
```

if any one knows the way or better way to do this ?

Thanks In advance !

Comment: post the expected output!

Comment: Thank You ! @Vignesh Kumar A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be are you looking for this

```
CASE WHEN PracticeItem = 'YES' AND si.ItemOrder = 1 THEN REPLACE(si.ItemOrder,1,'P1')  
     WHEN PracticeItem = 'YES' AND si.ItemOrder = 2 THEN REPLACE(si.ItemOrder,2,'P2')  
     WHEN PracticeItem = 'NO' THEN si.ItemOrder - SUM(CASE WHEN PracticeItem = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) END AS ItemOrder
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
     af.OldFormCode,
     CASE WHEN PracticeItem = 'YES' AND si.ItemOrder = 1 THEN REPLACE(si.ItemOrder,1,'P1')  
          WHEN PracticeItem = 'YES' AND si.ItemOrder = 2 THEN REPLACE(si.ItemOrder,2,'P2')  
          WHEN PracticeItem = 'NO' THEN si.ItemOrder - SUM(CASE WHEN PracticeItem = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) END AS ItemOrder ,ISNULL(bi.BankItemCode,'')as BankItemCode,iv.Code,
     ISNULL((SELECT AltTag FROM display WHEN Id IN (SELECT DisplayVersionId FROM ItemDisplay where itemId = iv.ID)),'') AS AltTag,
     iv.PracticeItem, af.Code AS AssessmentFormCode, af.ModalityId, af.ID 
FROM SectionItem si Left join AssessmentFormSection afs on si.SectionId= afs.Id 
LEFT JOIN AssessmentForm af ON afs.AssessmentFormId = af.ID
LEFT JOIN ItemView iv ON iv.ID = si.ItemId
LEFT JOIN BankItemView bi ON bi.ItemId = si.ItemId
LEFT JOIN Draft d ON (d.ItemId = si.ItemId and d.Id = CAST((SUBSTRING(si.FinalDraftVersion,3,(CHARINDEX('.',si.FinalDraftVersion,0)-3))) as int))
LEFT JOIN ItemStatistics ist ON ist.ItemId = iv.ID and ist.AssessmentId = af.ID
WHERE af.ID in (3287,3251)  
ORDER BY af.ID,si.ItemOrder
```